# DataGrid: Partial binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Let me try and state the simplest version of the question:

Can I have an UNBOUND dropdown-type column in my BOUND DataGrid?

Here is an example if the above statement is too abstract to understand:

A `DataGrid` named `dgStudents` that is bound to a `DataTable` named `dtStudents`, showing a few of the columns of the table, say Name, Age and City, all being simple `DataGridTextColumn`s. I want to add a 4th column to my grid named say FavSports that is a simple dropdown type column, bound to a static list of common sports. The most important thing here is that (unlike other 3 columns) this dropdown column DOES NOT have a corresponding column in the `DataTable`. It'll just be required for the life of the `DataGrid`, so I'm not storing it anywhere.

I have tried the following:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{StaticResource Sports}">
```

where `Sports` is an array defined right within XAML:

```
<x:Array x:Key="Sports" Type="sys:String">
    <sys:String>Football</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Hockey</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Tennis</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

Can't get this to work for the life of me. The dropdown does display and user can select a value out of it that does show after user moves to another cell, but that's about it. After user comes back to that cell, the drop-down appears empty and even if user then leaves the cell without clicking the dropdown, the previous value is gone.

Comment: Derive a class from Student and add the column.  Bind to the derived class instead of the data table...

Comment: Thanks Garry. I have that idea in my mind, but the underlying data source is a Typed DataSet returned by a web service. Deriving a class from it and adding custom properties to it will create a lot more work than I can handle at this point.

Comment: That's what ViewModels are for. Create a proper ViewModel for this.

Comment: Policy injection can also handle this...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to bind to your `StaticResource`, try this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Sports}}">
```